# how to ignore directories in git in any folder

Tags: linux, git

I have many folders in the root directory of git.

and every folder and subdirectory will have folder call `mytemp` and `.hg`

how can i ignore all the files and subfolders inside those two dirs.

i can't mention the path as they wiull be in many folders

Comment: Even a cursory reading of the documentation will give you your answer.  Was there something you found confusing there?

Comment: i thought , i need to give the full path , and that dir was in every directory , so i was confused that way

Answer (score 1):

add a .gitignore file in the root of your project with these 2 patterns:

```
mytemp/
.hg/
```